# why my program not working on phone but working on bluestacks

Tags: android, crash, settings

I created a program and it works fine. I'm testing in bluestack and doesn't exist any problem. When I try to install my program on phone then it is not installed. I guess that a problem comes from SDK, so try to install program on other phones with API 24 and 26, APK is installed, but when run program, stopped.

my program gradle is: 
    -compileSdkVersion 25, 
    -buildToolsVersion "25.0.3", 
    -minSdkVersion 14, 
    -targetSdkVersion 25

```
my bluestacks property is: 
-version: 4, 
-API: 25, 
-model: OnePlus A5000, 
-android: 7.1.1, 
-ram: 1500 M, 
-core: 2)
```

I guess problem does't come form program, it comes from Android Studio setting so,I create a simple project (default project: hello world) without any changes and API set in 9. A program run in bluestack, but stopping in phone. (it seems to me when click on program for a moment program is run after stopping)

this is Activity:

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
   import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
```

}

this is XML layout:

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.behnam_pc.test1_hello_world.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is gradle:

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

         android {
             compileSdkVersion 25
             buildToolsVersion "25.0.3"
             defaultConfig {
                 applicationId "com.example.behnam_pc.test1_hello_world"
                 minSdkVersion 9
                 targetSdkVersion 25
                 versionCode 1
                 versionName "1.0"
                 testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
             }
             buildTypes {
                 release {
                     minifyEnabled false
                     proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                 }
             }
         }

         dependencies {
             compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
             androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
                 exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
             })
             compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
             compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7'
             testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
        }
```

Anybody, please tell me where a problem comes from?

Comment: Edit your question, and add the error from logcat that you're getting on real devices.

Comment: 'increase your minSdkVersion upto you device API leval'

Comment: @MuhmmadUmair this solution if work, just good for one device.  what we should do for other device?

Comment: if a user have an old device having CupCake i think he should not have the right to say some apps are not working on it. that guy has to change the device, what is your opinion.??

Comment: This will not work on just one device it will work on all the device have API level more then this.

Comment: @MuhmmadUmair i don't think the "hello world" is special program, that user should use new device!!!!

Comment: it not deppends upon programm it deppends upon application. You may develop what's app in that application after removing 'Hello World' program